# Warnings in php code

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

> Warning: array_keys() expects parameter 1 to be array, string given in
>   /home/hennacur/public_html/shop/wp-content/themes/montezuma/includes/image_meta.php
>   on line 34
>
> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in
>   /home/hennacur/public_html/shop/wp-content/themes/montezuma/includes/image_meta.php
>   on line 40

```
                                                 function bfa_image_size() {
$meta = wp_get_attachment_metadata();
echo $meta['width']. '&times;' . $meta['height'];
    }


    function bfa_image_meta( $args = '' ) {

$defaults = array(
    'keys' => '',
    'before' => '', 
    'after' => '',
    'item_before' => '', 
    'item_after' => '',
    'item_sep' => ' &middot; ',
    'key_before' => '',
    'key_after' => ': ',
    'value_before' => '',
    'value_after' => '',
    'display_empty' => FALSE    
);

$r = wp_parse_args( $args, $defaults );
extract( $r, EXTR_SKIP );

$meta = wp_get_attachment_metadata();

$string_array = array();

       // All keys, alphabetically sorted, as provided by wp_get_attachment_metadata()
if( $keys == '' ) {
    $array_keys = array_keys( $meta['image_meta'] );  ---***line34***       
// Only keys specificed in parameter:
} else {
    $array_keys = array_map( 'trim', explode( ',', $keys ) );
}

foreach( $array_keys as $key ) { --***line 40***

    $value = $meta['image_meta'][$key];

    if( $display_empty === TRUE || ( $value != '' && $value != '0' ) ) {

        if( $key == 'created_timestamp' )
            // Transform timestamp into readable date, based on default WP date/time settings:
            $value = date( get_option('date_format') . ' - ' . get_option('time_format'), $value );

        // Prettify key
        $key = ucwords( str_replace( '_', ' ', $key ) );
        $key = $key == 'Iso' ? 'ISO' : $key;


        $key = str_replace( 
            array(
                'Aperture',
                'Credit',
                'Camera',
                'Caption',
                'Created Timestamp',
                'Copyright',
                'Focal Length',
                'ISO',
                'Shutter Speed',
                'Title'
            ),
            array(
                __( 'Aperture', 'montezuma' ),
                __( 'Credit', 'montezuma' ),
                __( 'Camera', 'montezuma' ),
                __( 'Caption', 'montezuma' ),
                __( 'Timestamp', 'montezuma' ),
                __( 'Copyright', 'montezuma' ),
                __( 'Focal Length', 'montezuma' ),
                __( 'ISO', 'montezuma' ),
                __( 'Shutter Speed', 'montezuma' ),
                __( 'Title', 'montezuma' )
            ),      
            $key
        );
```

I have the above code. What could be cause of the warnings that are appearing?

Comment: Resisit from naming your variables like reserved words - it's just a good habit that will keep you away from errors in future. And add `var_dump($meta['image_meta']);` to see what `$meta['image_meta']` really is and contains

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The warning explains it all.

`array_keys() expects parameter 1 to be array, string given` is telling you that a string was passed to `array_keys()` instead of an array.

Thus, `$meta['image_meta']` is probably not an array.

As a result, `$array_keys` is not being set as an array, leading to your next warning, when you try to apply `foreach` to it.

Comment: function bfa_image_size() {
 $meta = wp_get_attachment_metadata();
 echo $meta['width']. '&times;' . $meta['height'];
}


function bfa_image_meta( $args = '' ) {

 $defaults = array(
  'keys' => '',
  'before' => '', 
  'after' => '',
  'item_before' => '', 
  'item_after' => '',
  'item_sep' => ' &middot; ',
  'key_before' => '',
  'key_after' => ': ',
  'value_before' => '',
  'value_after' => '',
  'display_empty' => FALSE 
 );

 $r = wp_parse_args( $args, $defaults );
 extract( $r, EXTR_SKIP );
 
 $meta = wp_get_attachment_metadata();
 
 $string_array = array();

Comment: @karu: Please don't put code in a comment. It become incomprehensible. Also... what are you trying to say in this comment?

Comment: actually it is defined as a array

Comment: If, as WebnetMobile.com suggests, you add `var_dump($meta['image_meta']);` to your code, you'll probably find that it's not. PHP is warning you that it isn't.

Answer (score 1):

Try this (you can see this warning because $array_keys have type as string or something alse) if stetmen:

```
 if(is_array($array_keys) && !empty($array_keys)) { // foreach stetment here }
```